# How to sort table view number string numerically after row deletion

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table view that adds rows on a button press.  The rows are numbered from a string `itmeNo`  in ascending order for each row.  My problem is when user deletes a row, the numbers are no longer in order.

ie 1,2,3,4,5,

if user deletes row 3and 4 they are numbered

1,2,5

Im a bit stuck on how to sort numerically?  where I have `[self.observations count] + 1];` can I change this perhaps so `itemNo` always sorts ascending numerically

In summary I always want my table view rows number string to always be sequentially numbered

A bit of reach but so far ive tried `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the delete method and playing around with method allowing re ordering of table view.

```
 - (void)addObservationButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
LogCmd();
Observation *observation = [[ICObservationManager manager] newObservation];
observation.createdAt = [NSDate date];
observation.modifiedAt = [NSDate date];
observation.certificate = self.certificate;
observation.itemNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.observations count] + 1];
[self.certificate addObservationsObject:observation];
[self loadData];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.observations.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return [self.certificate.observations count];
}



 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ObservationsCellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
Observation *observation = [self.observations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *itemLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@",
                       observation.itemNo,
                       (observation.item.length ? observation.item : @"No description")];
cell.textLabel.text = itemLabel;

return cell;
}

 //Delete observations

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.observations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.appDelegate saveContext];
    [self.observations removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 }

}
```

Comment: you should retrive your last array objectAtIndex value of id and then add + 1 to it and then store new one..

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, could you expand a bit on that as not quite sure I understand

Comment: I have pasted code below

Comment: 1,2,5 is still in order, it just isn't contiguous, and it doesn't match the ordinality of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code :-

```
Observation *observation = [self.observations objectAtIndex:[self.observations count]-1];
int lastValue = [observation.itemNo intValue];
lastValue++;
```

`lastValue` is max value you can use

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you again, unfortunately  this does not re order my table view number string.  Its just the same  Unless im not implementing it correctly of course. Ive tried it my delete method and add method

Comment: I added it to`//delete observations` method, that didn't work so I added it to, `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Add this code in addObservationButtonPressed  function and replace this line observation.itemNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.observations count] + 1]; with observation.itemNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", lastValue];

Comment: This just crashes app, thanks for your help anyway.  Plus it duplicates *Observation

Comment: on which line your application crashes?

Comment: terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds for empty array' either way its duplicating `observations`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.observations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.appDelegate saveContext];
    [self.observations removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//need to add these lines
 NSSortDescriptor *sortByUploaded =[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itmeNo"ascending:YES];

  NSArray *sortDescriptorArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByUploaded,nil];

 self.observations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.observations sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArr]];


    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 }
```

}

Let me know if its not working

Answer (score 0):

When you are deleting rows from `UITableView` just sort it to the order again you want as @**rohit** does and then delete the row and reload your table according to order. Hope this helps.